# How to write single-valued lines from reading a multi-valued delimited file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, delimiter

I have a quick question, and I am sure most of you have an answer to this.

I have a delimited file with the following data:

```
server1;user1;role
server1;user2;role,role 2
server2;user1;role,role 2,role 3
```

Please note that the role 'column' is comma-delimited and possibly with multi-valued information and names using spaces, different from the rest of the file that is semicolon-delimited and single-valued.

I need to show each 'role' into a different line, but related to the server and user information. For example:

```
server1;user1;role
server1;user2;role
server1;user2;role 2
server2;user1;role
server2;user1;role 2
server2;user1;role 3
```

Instead of having all roles on one server/user line, I require to have one role per line.

Do you have any suggestion to create this on a Bash script? I tried nested **while read** combos, and also **for** loops reading arrays, but so far I was unable to accomplished that (I know that probably I will have to use those functions, but in different manner).

This is the Bash script I have been working on:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/file/input.csv"
output="/file/output.csv"
declare -a ARRAYROLES
while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3
do
  ARRAYROLES=($f3)
  field1=$f1
  field2=$f2
  for element in "${ARRAYROLES[@]}"
  do
    echo "$field1;$field2;$element" >> "$output"
  done
  field1=''
  field2=''
done < "$input"
```

And this is the output that I have so far (pretty close but not good enough):

```
server1;user1;role
server1;user2;role,role
server1;user2;2
server2;user1;role,role
server2;user1;2,role
server2;user1;3
```

Note that the role 'column' is divided per spaces (I am sure that is because of the **for element** statement reading the array)

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Andres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
ARRAYROLES=($f3)
```

to

```
IFS=, read -ra ARRAYROLES <<< "$f3"
```

Comment: Jonas, thank you for your answer. It worked with your change, and also I feel relief that 90% of my code was OK at least.

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS=';' read -r server user roles; do
    IFS=',' read -r -a arr <<< "$roles"
    printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]/#/$server;$user;}"
done < "$input" > "$output"
```

---

From `help read`:

```
-a array  
     assign the words read to sequential indices of the array variable ARRAY,
     starting at zero
```

`${arr[@]/#/...}` is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) that in this case eliminated the need for an extra loop.

Comment: PesaThe, thanks for your answer. It worked, and is now on my side to understand some of the statements, this code is so much compact than the one I have.